# Play Music from iTunes in Terminal

Tags: terminal, itunes, mac, command-line, music

Is there a way to play music from iTunes with a Terminal command? I've tried to do this with the `afplay` command, but the music won't play because of a locked mp4 music file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AppleScript to play Music via iTunes.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to play playlist "My Favorites"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the NeXTSTEP spirit-

```
open /path/to/file.m4p
```

which will open file.m4p in iTunes.